# MySQL count of the grouped two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this `user_logs` table:

```
user_id | operation | table
--------+-----------+-----------
1       | create    | restaurant
1       | create    | restaurant
1       | create    | dish type
1       | create    | dish type
1       | create    | dish type
1       | update    | dish name
1       | update    | dish name
1       | update    | dish name
1       | update    | restaurant
1       | update    | restaurant
```

I want to populate data for this table:

```
operation_on_table | count
-------------------+------
create restaurant  | 2
create dish type   | 3
update dish name   | 3
update restaurant  | 2
```

What I have done upto now is:

```
SELECT operation, count(operation) FROM user_logs
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY operation
```

It gives me this:

```
operation | count
----------+------
create    | 5
update    | 5
```

But this is not what I need.

How can I add table name to the count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `table` column in group by

```
SELECT operation,`table`, count(operation) 
FROM user_logs
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY operation,`table`
```

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` both columns and concatenate the columns inside select:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `operation`, `table`) AS `operation_on_table`
     , COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `user_logs`
WHERE `user_id` = 1
GROUP BY `operation`, `table`
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple query would do the work:

```
select operation, count(*) from (
   select concat(operation, ' ', `table`) `operation` from user_logs
) a group by operation
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can try

```
select operation,[table], count(operation) from  user_logs 
GROUP BY operation,[table]
```